# Invoke function on message

Tags: echo-area, error-handling, message

The `debug-on-message` variable tells Emacs to start the debugger when a matching message is displayed. How can I get Emacs to invoke my own function when a matching message is displayed?

My motivation in this case is to build a contingency engine for common errors. Not all of these are well-handled locally through `advice` or `unwind-protect`, so I would like to use the echo area (or equivalently the `*Messages*` buffer) as my input.

Example usage: `(do-on-message "Foo error" 'handle-foo)`

Comment: Perhaps you could set the `debugger` variable to a custom function. Not sure if that would work together with `debug-on-message`.

Comment: What is a contingency engine for error?!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could advise `message`.

But do you really need/want this to take effect for calls to `message`, i.e., including for calls that your code does not make?

If what you are really trying to do is "*build a contingency engine for common errors*" then it sounds like what it would be helpful to define your own error symbols. To do that, you use `define-error` - see the Elisp manual, node [Error Symbols](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Symbols.html).

And see these nodes:

- [Signaling Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signaling-Errors.html) for how to signal an error of a type that you define
- [Handling Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html) for how to handle errors, including those you define.

**Note:** In versions of Emacs prior to Emacs 24.4, there was no `define-error`. You accomplished the same thing using symbol property `error-conditions` (and you can still do this).  Here are the Emacs 24.4 and Emacs 24.3 definitions of error condition `bookmark-error-no-filename`, for instance:

Emacs 24.4 (+):

```el
(define-error 'bookmark-errors nil)
(define-error 'bookmark-error-no-filename
  "Bookmark has no associated file (or directory)" 'bookmark-errors)
```

Emacs 24.3:

```el
(put 'bookmark-error-no-filename
     'error-conditions
     '(error bookmark-errors bookmark-error-no-filename))
(put 'bookmark-error-no-filename
     'error-message
     "Bookmark has no associated file (or directory)")
```

---

P.S. If my guess is right about what your question is really about, please consider editing the question (at least the title) to make it clear.

Comment: I also would not advise `message`.  I tried this once, and it resulted in some serious stability issues that were quite difficult to track down.